# What does \draw(0, \x, 4) mean?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to easily view latex arguments ? What does `\draw(0, \x, 4)` mean ? Here only got 2 input arguments https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/27/tikz-series-pt1.html

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in{0,...,4}
{   \draw (0,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,4);
    \draw (\x ,0,4) -- (\x ,4,4);
    \draw (4,\x ,4) -- (4,\x ,0);
    \draw (\x ,4,4) -- (\x ,4,0);
    \draw (4,0,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
    \draw (0,4,\x ) -- (4,4,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are also 3D coordinates supported out of the box in TikZ.  See “13.2.1 Canvas, XYZ, and Polar Coordinate Systems” in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

> [image]